# some clarification regarding hdd mount

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, rsync

when I run the command `lsblk`, the output is like this:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    1  1.8T  0 disk
|-sda1   8:1    1  381M  0 part /boot
|-sda2   8:2    1    1K  0 part
|-sda5   8:5    1  1.8T  0 part /
`-sda6   8:6    1   24G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1  1.8T  0 disk
`-sdb1   8:17   1  1.8T  0 part /media/sys-bkp
```

what I understand is that when I cd in to `/media/sys-bkp`
I am in the second drive `sdb1`

Now when I go to say `/media/sys-bkp/var/www/cbsindia.in/web`
and run a ls command, it lists all the files as in

`/var/www/cbsindia.in/web`

some time back I ran a command 
`rsync -avhx / /media/sys-bkp/`

but `cbsindia.in/web/` in `sdb1` there should be no file, as I copied it today only, also if I delete the file listed in `sdb1` it is deleted from `sda5` which shows that even after mount it is listing the files from `sda5`

I must be doing something horribly wrong here, don't know what.

Looking for some guidance, what I am missing.

update as per the comment:

```
root@server2:~# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="01ca4016-efd6-46c4-959a-af70ed4c7335" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="20886952-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="e14b3398-d632-410f-ab61-a5ad4893d7d6" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="20886952-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="330a1bfc-f5ba-405d-b4b3-59f3f30c7594" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="20886952-06"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="f0180beb-37be-4c09-b632-5188b0edcb6f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a950ecb8-01"
```

Comment: rsync doesn't make bi-directional synch, just from left-to-right. All you do in sda5 will be reflected in sdb1, the opposite will not be done.

Comment: Exactly. rsync was used much earlier. but now if I am mounting the second hdd using the mount point, it still shows the files of 1st hdd.

Comment: Do you mean if you umount sdb1 and  delete a sda5 file, when you mount sdb1 again, sda5 deleted file is restored?

Comment: no. it behaves like I am accessing the same disk with mount or without mount. so if I delete from the mount it shows as deleted in sda5 even when unmounted. If delete from sda5 and mount sdb it doesn't show the deleted file.

Comment: Execute `sudo blkid` at terminal and compare UUIDs, if they have the same UUID, great chance to be the same partition.

Comment: No I have updated the question with the command you suggested. UUID is unique and not same.

Comment: It seems there is any [backup or synchronizing active service](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem) in your computer. Look if any of these I linked here are enabled.